# How do I know my Application is being closed?

Tags: android

I want to find a way to determine if my application is being closed/destroyed (whatever the correct term is) by the OS.  I found an `onCreate()` method in the Android `Application` class, but no `onDestroy()`, or an equivalent. ([Application Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/Android/app/Application.html))

While the Activity lifecycle would normally be sufficient, I have resources that take time to free up and need to be used across multiple Activities. It would be costly and unrealistic to handle those resources on any of the ending lifecycle calls of an activity (`onPause`, `onStop`, or `onDestroy`).

(To clarify, I do not want to programatically close my Android application. I have found plenty of documentation and SO questions on that. I am not interested in the Activity lifecycle either.) I don't care about controlling when my Application closes, but I would like a heads up when it is going to do so.

Comment: Sorry, but you do not understand how applications on Androids works internally. There's no such thing like application close unless your application process is killed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to find a way to determine if my application is being closed/destroyed (whatever the correct term is) by the OS.

Sorry, but that does not happen. As WebnetMobile.com indicates in his comment, your application is destroyed by Android terminating the process, and you are not notified of this fact.

> I have resources that take time to free up

Since you elected not to explain what these "resources" are and why they "take time to free up", it will be difficult for anyone to assist you in coming up with an alternative plan.

Answer (score 1):

What I would recommend is having one function (let's call it killMyApp), and a global count of activities currently running (actCount).  In each onCreate, increment actCount.  In each onDestroy, decrement actCount then, if actCount==0, call killMyApp, which will clean up all the leftover goodies.